# Question about average theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I understand the concept but I am having trouble constructing a competent proof for this is it correct or is there a better approach?:

Prove that if $a,b \in F$, where $F$ an ordered field so that $a<b$ then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
there are numbers $x_i \in F$ such that $a<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_{n-1}<x_n<b$

I will attempt this using induction:

Base Case:

Assume $a<b$ then $2a<a+b$ and $a+b<2b$

$\implies a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$

Inductive Step:

Assume

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$
there are numbers $x_i \in F$ such that $a<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_{k-1}<x_k<b$

Consider $x_k<b$ then $2x_k<b+x_k$ and $x_k+b<2b$

$\implies 2x_k<b+x_k<2b$

$\implies x_k< \frac{b+x_k}{2}<b$

So let $x_{k+1}=\frac{b+x_k}{2}$

and $a<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_{k-1}<x_k<x_{k+1}<b$

Thus

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
there are numbers $x_i \in F$ such that $a<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_{n-1}<x_n<b$

Comment: Without more information about F the statement is not true.   For example, if F is a finite set, it is definitely not true.

Comment: @Doug M Sorry F is an ordered field

Comment: It seems like most of the statement/question is missing!

Comment: @TedShifrin I am trying to rid of my account without having the history kept

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a < b$, then $0 < b - a$, so
$$
0 < b-a < 2(b-a) < \cdots < n(b-a).
$$ 
Then
$$
0 < \frac{b-a}n < \frac{2(b-a)}n < \cdots < \frac{(n-1)(b-a)}n < b - a.
$$
So
$$
a < \frac{b-a}n + a < \frac{2(b-a)}n + a < \cdots < \frac{(n-1)(b-a)}n< b.
$$

Comment: thank you so much